# How to call method automatically when switching views in TabBar app with a single ViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

My application uses UITabBarController with 4 tabs.  Each tab will have a UIWebView along with other types of objects.  When the app launches I need to call the method for this first webView to retrieve my web content.

I have this method in my viewdidLoad:
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getAdvisory) withObject:nil];

The web content on the first tab works fine.  I'm just at a loss to get my other tabs to load up.  I think I would use a switch or if statement but I do not know how to tell which view is loaded.

I need to do the same for the rest of the tabs.  The app has a single view controller.
When setting an action using a button everything works fine.  I just do not know how to call the method when a different view (tapping tabs) loads.

Also when retrieving data from the network, what are the best methods to use to not tie up the main thread?  I have read where NSOperation would be used in this scenario.  Is this correct? If so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe by using a user delegate of your UITabBar and the method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

> Sent to the delegate when the user selects a tab bar item.

See [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks for the reponse B, I'm going to read up on that method for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this problem and there is a better method.

Simply override the viewDidAppear method and insert the code you want to execute when the view does appear!

As an example the following code will call myMethod.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [self MyMethod];
}
```